# Running python 3 on 64bit, packages updated; ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, numpy, dll

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

This is the error I receive. I have updated my packages and am running on a x64 system. Any reason why I have this issue?

Comment: If you are running python 3.x and getting an error in the 2.7 Python directory, surely you are trying to init numpy from 2.7. Add python 3.x to your path and remove python 2.7?

Comment: I have check the versions and it should not be an issue